# I have WETH in my ETH wallet but I can't send it

Tags: tokens, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, transfer, wrapped-tokens

As you see, I have 1.7 WETH. When I try to withdraw, it shows me this

[image: Screenshot of balance]

[image: Screenshot of receiving wallet]

Comment: You probably do not have enough ETH to covert the transaction fee that has to be always paid in ETH

Answer (score 1):

Some exchanges, such as the one you posted, require you to trade a minimum amount of ETH (or tokens).

In this case, you are trying to send 0.00003111... WETH, but the exchange says you  need to send a minimum of 0.001.

In order to fix this, you will need to send more WETH to your account.